# Extract open, unsaved documents from TextEdit that is running from RAM content when it is in non-responsive state?

Tags: macos, crash, data-recovery, textedit, autosave

I know how to find unsaved TextEdit documents ordinarily. However, my computer's hard drive ran out of space and I have many open that are not autosaved anywhere as a result. I was using another app (Notes) and when I exported to PDF it made the app unresponsive. I force quit the Open and Save process that was showing as unresponsive and tried again. And I had the same result.

So I tried using TextEdit (where I have over 300 documents open...bad idea I know) to export this text I needed to save as a PDF. I badly assumed the problem relating to exporting was just with notes. But when I tried to export, it also caused the app to become unresponsive. And force quitting the Open and Save process doesn't help.

I was able to copy the files that are autosaved from the AutoSave folder, but there are about fifty that are not autosaved due to the HDD having been low on space when they were created.

Is there a way to capture them from where they are running in RAM?

Comment: Do you have developer tools (Xcode) installed?

Comment: Apple has introduced several memory security features that make this very unlikely. It's usually recommended to keep between 10% and 20% of a disk free -- even an SSD.